# linux unix sockets vs tcp sockets send buffer size

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, tcp, unix-socket

I am comparing how many bytes a send call can transfer when a socket is tcp and when it is  unix socket.

For unix domain socket the number is always 219264,but for TCP this number is much higher.Why is this difference? Both the programs are executed in the same machine

Note:sockets are in non blocking mode

checked the buffer size,these are the values

unix domain socket

```
receive buffer size =212992
send buffer size =212992
```

TCP socket

```
receive buffer size =1062000
send buffer size =2626560
```

can someone explain me why is this difference?

Comment: The fact is that the buffer sizes are finite and the exact size is not specified so either way you must deal with it. You can change the buffer size through `setsockopt()` and query it with `getsockopt()` if you need to, or just properly deal with `send()` returning fewer bytes than you requested.

Comment: @james no that I understood. What am asking is incase on unix sockets send only sends a very few bytes when compared to tcp sockets? In general both are sockets

Comment: If you only send a few bytes it doesn't matter from hell to breakfast time whether the buffer size is 219264 or something larger.

Comment: @user207421 i am send 10mb data,since for unix sockets send buffer size is low,number of pollout events is also more.this i want to avoid.

Comment: @user207421 which means in case of high performance applications unix sockets cant be used?

Answer (score 0):

The tcp buffer is used for packages which have been sent but not acknowledged by the other end yet and for packages which have been received out of order and are waiting for delayed packages to arrive before presented to the application. Of course packages will also stay in the buffer as long as the consuming application doesn't `read()` the data.

Over UNIX sockets, packages which are waiting for ACK, or the order of packages is not an issue, therefore the buffer can be smaller.

Comment: what do you mean by "order of packages is not an issue".are you saying data wont be recieved in the order they are sent?

Comment: Over the internet there is no guarantee that packages will arrive in the same order they've been sent, right. TCP is waiting until the order of packages can be restored before presenting them (their payload)  to the client when receiving data